# Deleted Firebase Facebook User now can't login

Tags: android, facebook, firebase, firebase-authentication

So I was trying to make the login with facebook to also create a document on my firestorm. But since I was already  logged in iwht my facebook account, I decided to delete it on my Firebase Authentication Tab.

I think this messed up the whole thing since everything was working before I deleted my facebook user and I reverted all the changes,

This is the error

```
Process: com.reecreate.woderator2, PID: 7586
  java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=64206, result=-1, data=Intent { (has extras) }} to activity {com.reecreate.woderator2/com.reecreate.woderator.Controller.LoginActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApi.zzb(com.google.android.gms.common.api.internal.zzdd)' on a null object reference
      at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:4089)
      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:4132)
      at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap20(ActivityThread.java)
      at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1533)
      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119)
      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886)
      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)
   Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApi.zzb(com.google.android.gms.common.api.internal.zzdd)' on a null object reference
      at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzdvv.zzb(Unknown Source)
      at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzdwc.zza(Unknown Source)
      at com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth.signInWithCredential(Unknown Source)
      at com.reecreate.woderator.Controller.LoginActivity.firebaseLogin(LoginActivity.kt:120)
      at com.reecreate.woderator.Controller.LoginActivity.access$firebaseLogin(LoginActivity.kt:31)
      at com.reecreate.woderator.Controller.LoginActivity$onCreate$1.onSuccess(LoginActivity.kt:74)
      at com.reecreate.woderator.Controller.LoginActivity$onCreate$1.onSuccess(LoginActivity.kt:71)
      at com.facebook.login.LoginManager.finishLogin(LoginManager.java:639)
      at com.facebook.login.LoginManager.onActivityResult(LoginManager.java:244)
      at com.facebook.login.LoginManager$1.onActivityResult(LoginManager.java:173)
      at com.facebook.internal.CallbackManagerImpl.onActivityResult(CallbackManagerImpl.java:95)
      at com.reecreate.woderator.Controller.LoginActivity.onActivityResult(LoginActivity.kt:114)
      at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:6932)
      at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:4085)
      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:4132) 
      at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap20(ActivityThread.java) 
      at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1533) 
      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) 
      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119) 
      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886) 
      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)
```

And this is the Facebook function

```
CallbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create()
    loginFacebookBtn.setReadPermissions("email", "public_profile")
    loginFacebookBtn.registerCallback(mCallbackManager, object : FacebookCallback<LoginResult> {
        override fun onSuccess(loginResult: LoginResult) {
            val credential = FacebookAuthProvider.getCredential(loginResult.accessToken.token)
            firebaseLogin(credential)
        }

        override fun onCancel() {
            Log.d("Cancel", "facebook:onCancel")
            updateUI(null)
        }

        override fun onError(error: FacebookException) {
            Log.e("Error", "facebook:onError", error)
            updateUI(null)
        }
    })


}

override fun onStart() {
    super.onStart()
    // Check if user is signed in (non-null) and update UI accordingly.
    val currentUser = auth.currentUser
    updateUI(currentUser)
}

override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)

    if (requestCode == GOOGLE_SIGN_IN) {
        val result = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInResultFromIntent(data)
        if (result.isSuccess) {
            if (result.signInAccount != null) {
                val account = result.signInAccount!!
                val credential = GoogleAuthProvider.getCredential(account.idToken, null)
                firebaseLogin(credential)
            }

        } else{
            Log.e("Error", "Could not signin google")
        }
    }  else {
        mCallbackManager.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)
    }
}

private fun firebaseLogin(credential: AuthCredential) {
    //        showProgressDialog()
    auth.signInWithCredential(credential)
            .addOnCompleteListener(this) { task ->
                if (task.isSuccessful) {
                    val user = auth.currentUser
                    updateUI(user)
                    val loginIntent = Intent(this, MainActivity::class.java)
                    startActivity(loginIntent)
                    // Start new activity.
                } else {
                    // If sign in fails, display a message to the user.
                    Log.e("Error", "signInWithCredential:failure", task.exception)
                    Toast.makeText(this, "Authentication failed.",
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                    updateUI(null)
                }

//                    hideProgressDialog()
                }
    }
```

Any ideas?

I am really lost here :/

Answer (score 0):

Disabling or deleting a user account does not fire an auth state change. Nor should it, the user is still authenticated. In at most an hour, Firebase Authentication will try to refresh the access token for the user. That refresh will fail, at which point the user will become unauthenticated and the auth state change event will fire.